# Get filtered data only on model object as result, angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code is like this

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div>Name only
    <input ng-model="search.name" />
    <br />
    <table id="searchObjResults">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends  | filter:search:strict  | limitTo:1">
            <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
            <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <button type="button" id="btn_submit" ng-click="submitForm()">Get rates</button>
</div>
```

```
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
    $scope.friends = [{
        name: 'John',
        phone: '555-1276'
    }, {
        name: 'Mary',
        phone: '800-BIG-MARY'
    }, {
        name: 'Mike',
        phone: '555-4321'
    }, {
        name: 'Adam',
        phone: '555-5678'
    }, {
        name: 'Julie',
        phone: '555-8765'
    }, {
        name: 'Juliette',
        phone: '555-5678'
    }];


    $scope.submitForm = function () {
        // i want to get the data here
    };

}]);
```

As you can see at a time only one `friend`  will be active on my screen. when I press my submit button, I want that data (filtered single row) to be the only value on my current `$scope.friends` so that I can send it to an external service as the selected data. Can any one point out what i need to do here
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2xqmkwx/)**

Note: I can't change the position of this button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not make your button part of the table row, since there will only ever be one? [Here is a JSFiddle showing it working in that fashion](http://jsfiddle.net/v2xqmkwx/3/).

The ng-click function handler for the button can then simply take a parameter that is the actual friendObj you are interested in:

```
 <button type="button" ng-click="submitForm( friendObj )">Get rates</button>
```

EDIT: There is actually a way to do this if you can't move the button; make the ng-repeat operate over a NEW array, which will be accessible outside of the ng-repeat. So your ng-repeat statement becomes:

```
<tr ng-repeat="friendObj in newArray = (friends  | filter:search:strict  | limitTo:1)">
```

And then your button can simply reference the one-element array:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="submitForm( newArray )">Get rates</button>
```

[Updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/v2xqmkwx/7/) :-)

Comment: I can't really change the position of that button. its out of question

Comment: Ok, then you'll have to do something along the lines of what Eric mentioned - either using-change or a watch, and store what the selection is everytime it updates :)

Comment: Your second answer is awesome.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you put the filter in the controller instead of the view, you could set a variable like `$scope.result` that the `submitForm` function could use. For example, in your HTML, you could add an `ng-change` directive to your search field like so:

```
<input ng-model="search.name" ng-change="updateResult()" />
```

Then, instead of using `ng-repeat`, you'd use `ng-show` to show the one result, or hide the row if there is no result:

```
<tr ng-show="result">
    <td>{{result.name}}</td>
    <td>{{result.phone}}</td>
</tr>
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.search = {name: ''};
$scope.updateResult = function() {
    $scope.result = $filter('filter')($scope.friends, $scope.search.name)[0];
}
$scope.updateResult();

// ...

$scope.submitForm = function() {
    // $scope.result can be used here
}
```

**EDIT:** The advantage of this approach is it's a bit DRYer because you don't re-filter inside `submitForm`. MarcoS's approach has the advantage of being a lot shorter!

Comment: Interesting answer, I was considering mentioning that, but it does have the downside that the updateResult() function will be called for every keypress. Perhaps ok in this example, but should be noted!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$scope.submitForm = function () {
  var data = $filter('filter')($scope.friends, $scope.search.name);
};
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v2xqmkwx/6/).